# Removing double quotes in Smarty PHP

Tags: php, smarty

Im attempting to remove double quotes passed in a request parameter string.
I know Smarty has a escape:'html' function however Id rather just remove all ".

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.replace.php), there's a replace modifier:

```
{$yourValue|replace:'"':''}
```